# MySQL is malfunctioning

Tags: mysql, logging, ports

My xampp has been malfunctioning, whenever I start mysql it runs until it suddenly kills itself. it says that a port is blocked. In advance,Thankyou for your help!

The error_log.txt is as follows:

```
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 5936616 and 5936616 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 5936626 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2017-02-10 10:33:58 3748 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2017-02-10 10:33:59 3748 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-02-10 10:33:59 3748 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-02-10 10:33:59 3748 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.30-76.3 started; log sequence number 5936626
2017-02-10 10:33:59 7116 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-02-10 10:34:00 3748 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-02-10 10:34:00 3748 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-02-10 10:34:00 3748 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2017-02-10 10:34:00 3748 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2017-02-10 10:34:00 3748 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: "Whenever I start MySQL..." What are you doing to start it? Before you start it, did you check whether it's already running as a service?

Comment: Note this error: *"Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?"* OS X comes with one version of MySQL, and then XAMPP tries to run another one. You can't run two services on the same port. So you must stop the MySQL service that's already running.

Comment: Thank you Bill. But I have tried stopping it before but sadly, it didn't work. I just uninstalled then again installed my mysql :) and everything went good again. :)